# Backbone - How to specify attributes to save?

Tags: backbone.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone.js partial model update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273369/backbone-js-partial-model-update)

I have system where I have to download a series of objects from a rails app. When they arrive, I add more information onto them, (mainly converting coordinates to google's LatLng and other overlays for a map).

The problem is that when I `save()` the model, ALL the attributes are appended to the request, where I only want some of then to save (I don't want to save the LatLng objects and other overlays, just the attributes that were downloaded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate question: [Backbone.js partial model update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273369/backbone-js-partial-model-update)

the gist of it is: there is no default support for partially sending a model to the server (at the moment). But if you really need this, it can be done, by overriding the toJSON methods, which are used by the backbone sync functionality.