# Saving only one attribute

Tags: backbone.js

I have a model for which I would like to save only the attribute `title`. This is what I have tried:

```
myBook.model.save(['title']);
```

The problem is that `request.body` is the whole `myBook.toJSON()` object, instead of just the relevant attribute `title`. Is that by design, or am I doing something stupid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone - How to specify attributes to save?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637083/backbone-how-to-specify-attributes-to-save)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design.

`save` calls `Backbone.sync` to persist changes to your backend, which in turn does, among other things:

```
if (!params.data && model && (method == 'create' || method == 'update')) {
  params.contentType = 'application/json';
  params.data = JSON.stringify(model.toJSON()); // <-- jsonifies the entire model
}
```

There are plenty of ways to override this behavior. You can give your model a `sync` method, in which case it will be called instead of Backbone's default `sync`. Or you could just override Backbone.sync to do what you want.

However, most server-side frameworks will be able to handle receiving the full JSON object and only updating the changed content. Why do you need to only send the changed attribute to the server?

Side note: the first parameter to `save` should be a hash of attributes: so `{title: newBookTitle}` as opposed to `['title']`. But I'm guessing that was probably just a quick example typo.