# Another Backbone post part data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want use Backbone.save the model,and the model's nest data need to be filter,so i use

```
model.save(null,{
    success: ...,
    error:...,
    data: {
        id:null,
        name:'myname',
        nestmodel: {
            id:'xx'/*Other data i don't need it,so just id column*/
        }
    }
}
```

And I don't want to use `patch` HTTP METHOD. Because i just add a new model,not change part data.

And i don't want to post some `nestmodel` data,Because it's to big and i just want the id is ok.

And `nestmodel` just need the id.

I have read Exclude model properties when syncing (Backbone.js) and Backbone.js/express.js parameters for `model.save()`

There is a way to solve that problem.

That's whole my code:

```
 sync: function(method, model, options) {
  var data, orderSuiteItems;
  if (method === 'create') {
    options.url = this.url;
  } else {
    // MUST setting the url .options's url is undefined
    options.url = this.url + this.idUrl(this.get('id'));
  }
  // IF `create` or `update` , pick the we need properties
  if (method === 'create' || method === 'update') {
    orderSuiteItems = [];
    if (this.has('orderSuiteItems')) {
      // Because the `dishes` and `dishesUnitPrice` have a lot of prop,
      // Each of `dishes` or `dishesUnitPrice` may each have 10K data
      orderSuiteItems = _.map(this.get('orderSuiteItems'), function(osi) {
        return {
          id: osi.id,
          qty: osi.qty,
          servingQty: osi.qty,
          confirmQty: osi.confirmQty,
          deleted: osi.deleted,
          orderItem: _.pick(osi.orderItem, 'id'),
          dishes: _.pick(osi.dishes, 'id'), // HAVE a large prop 
          dishesUnitPrice: _.pick(osi.dishesUnitPrice, 'id'), // HAVE a large prop 
          orderItemStatus: osi.orderItemStatus,
          piece: osi.piece
        };
      });
    }
    data = {
      id: this.get('id'),
      order: this.get('order'),
      price: this.get('price'),
      dishes: _.pick(this.get('dishes'), 'id', 'isSuite'),
      dishesUnitPrice: _.pick(this.get('dishesUnitPrice'), 'id'),
      qty: this.get('qty'),
      servingQty: this.get('servingQty'),
      confirmQty: this.get('confirmQty'),
      sum: this.get('sum'),
      orderSuiteItems: orderSuiteItems,
      orderItemStatus: this.get('orderItemStatus')
    };
    // Setting attrs with pick data.
    options.attrs = data;
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
  } else {
    return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
  }
}
```

Comment: You just want to send the `id`? It's not clear what you're looking for.

Comment: I want the Nestmodel just need the id

Comment: Just call jQuery's Ajax method and post the data you want if your needs aren't met by built in API.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273369/backbone-js-partial-model-update

Comment: I override the sync method it's ok now.

Comment: @WiredPrairie that link is a good well.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you just put the `data` option for the sake of the example's clarity.

Anyway, how about using `unset` to remove your attribute just before using `Model#save`? Re-set it just afterwards.
Another solution would be to override the `Model#save` method.
You could also *shadow* the same method by defining it as a property and not in the prototype (that'd give you the opportunity to switch back).

Solution #1 or something similar would be the easiest. Solution #2 may be more, let's say, risky, but would have maybe less boilerplate. I would use the #3 only in some very specific case (can't even think about one as of now) that would include: object being a singleton (because we're not using the prototype)(or only in a limited number), need to switch the 2 modes a lot, better to have only 1 method.

**Edit:**
Solution #1:

```
var nestedModel = myModel.get('nestmodel');
myModel.save('nestmodel', nestedModel.id, {silent: true});
myModel.set('nestmodel', nestedModel, {silent: true});
```

I added the `silent` flag as I don't know if you're listening to your `nestmodel` attribute's changes. I'll add code for the other solutions if this one doesn't suit you.

Comment: @WiredPrairie are you referring to the fact that `save` doesn't return the object or something else?

Comment: Save returns a boolean or jqxhr.

Comment: But now, why set `nestmodel` back into `myModel`?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I override the sync method.is ok.

Comment: @WiredPrairie simply to restore the model's state.

Comment: @Loamhoof if set the `nestmodel` with `silent`,it would not change listen events.BUT if data return I must change the model,so it's not a good idea.

Comment: @sjbwylbs what would return? A new id for the nested model?

Comment: @Loamhoof Yes.new id for each other.

Comment: @sjbwylbs well I still don't see any problem with this method, but anyway as you seem to have found a solution that suits you, needless to continue the small talk.

Comment: Thanks to @Loamhoof  very much with all my wish.